# XCode 4.5, Facebook SDK 3.1 implementation resulting in "...selected destination does not support the architecture ..." error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk, linker

Presently getting the following error:

Cannot run on the Selected Destination

The selected destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is built.  Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software

This started happening after adding the new Facebook SDK to my project (adding the framework, adding -lsqlite3.0 to my Other Linker Flags build setting.

I've tried rebooting my computer; I've tried it on a different app (one of the one facebook instructs you to make to demonstrate the Login) and no matter what I do, I always get this error. Looked around on SO and found nothing that seemed to pertain to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the project file , under valid architectures by default armv7 , armv7s are added by Xcode 4.5 , if any of your static libraries are not compiled for armv7s you could get this error. So try removing armv7s

Comment: I tried doing this but did not know the appropriate formatting. Can I just write "armv7" or does it have to be formatted a certain way? The default text is: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT), which gives you arm7 and arm7s.

Comment: The default text for Architectures is: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and in my case it showing armv7 , armv7s. Also there is one for entry "valid  architectures" where i removed armv7s

Answer (score 0):

did you add the entire facebooksdk folder? if so it has an info.plist file in it, delete that file and you should be fine.

xcode gets confused when there are multiple info.plist files in a project

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, if you install the FacebookSDK and you add the resources folder to get the facebook image buttons there is a Info.plist file. XCodes goes weird with this info.plist file. I have deleted it, made a clean and now it works perfect :)
The best option is to move the project to other path. Adding and removing the libsql3.0 from lib dependencies sometimes works too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things that I have seen cause this error. Like already mentioned, make sure that the architecture defined in the build settings are correct for the project & any static libraries you're using.

One thing that causes this that I've run into quite a few times is that the "Product Name" specified in either the project or one of the targets build settings does not match the target name.

For example:
If you have a project named "MyProject" and you have a target named "SomeTarget", in the build settings for "SomeTarget", the Product Name (under "Packaging") has to be "SomeTarget". If it's not, for whatever reason, you will get this error.

We have a project at my work which we run a script on to change various things on so we can package apps separately depending on what we need to do. Whenever we add a new configuration to the script, if we don't add the part to change the product name we get this error every time.

Don't know if that will help your particular problem, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.